# how to answer would you be able to come in for an interview on {date} at {time}?

Tags: be, would, able-eable

how to answer would you be able to come in for an interview on `***date***` at

`***time***`?

is it okay to use :

1. I will be available at aforementioned date and time.

or

2. yes i would.

Comment: Both are acceptable but you might find repeating the time and date useful. It helps me remember it better and gives the asker a chance to double check they gave you the correct time.

Comment: I am not sure how this is at all a question about English. You could ask the exact same question about any language at all. The answer could be a "Yes, I would be available", or a "Yes, I would", or a "Sure thing", or a "Yes sir, I will gladly attend" or a "Never in a thousand years", or a "No way mate, I'm not coming" or a "Who is this?" They all mean different things and are used in different situations. In every language. You know what your situation is. We don't. You have all the context. We have none whatsoever. Frankly, the only person equpped to answer this question is yourself.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the level of formality you wish to set.  I feel that the first option you suggest is too formal, and the second option too informal.

In messages about job applications, people generally prefer to be quite formal, so your first option is a safe choice as long as you add the word 'the': *I will be available at the aforementioned date and time.*

However, the word 'aforementioned' is very formal and almost never used in conversation, so I would suggest a more natural-sounding alternative: *Yes, I am available at the time you suggest.  I look forward to meeting with you then.*